# Include header in multiple .csv file with cat linux

Tags: linux, linux-terminal

I need to include a .csv header in multiple .csv files at once by switching the name to:

> originalname1c.csv, originalname2c.csv, originalname3c.csv

Currently, the procedure is done as follows:

```
cat header.csv originalname1.csv > originalname1c.csv
cat header.csv originalname2.csv > originalname2c.csv
cat header.csv originalname3.csv > originalname3c.csv
```

Etc.

Is it possible to add header to multiple files as in the above example in a single command?

Answer (score 1):

Untested answer as a script :

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..50} do
   cat header.csv originalname${i}.csv > originalname${i}c.csv
done
```

Or as one-liner :

```
for i in {1..50} do cat header.csv originalname${i}.csv > originalname${i}c.csv; done
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. an additional one: what if the filenames were random? keeping the rule from: anyname.csv to anynamec.csv